# Content Security Policy in IIS header

Tags: https, iis-7, web-config, content-security-policy

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' '*';
               script-src 'self' https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com; 
               style-src 'self' https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com;
               img-src 'self'  https://ssl.gstatic.com/;
               font-src 'self' https://use.fontawesome.com"/>
```

Above are the CSP i have used to my site but its not working for me.

Can any once pls help on this

[its showing lot of errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k46U9.png)

Comment: H Dinesh, welcome to StackOverflow! I'd highly recommend reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better understanding of what types of questions StackOverflow is more likely to be helpful with. If these errors are coming from a site you created, it would be helpful to see the code so that we can help, but my initial guess is that there are some problems with the html.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your header is not formatted correctly. The script and style resource get blocked because you didn't enable unsafe-inline code.

Have you tried to specify 'unsafe-inline' for script-src and style-src?

```
   <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://tagmanager.google.com/ https://fonts.googleapis.com/ https://use.fontawesome.com;img-src 'self' https://ssl.gstatic.com/; font-src 'self' https://use.fontawesome.com;" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```